# Spring Security: Method Level Security Prevent Access to a Role

Tags: java, spring, security, soap, spring-security

Using Spring Security 5.2.X (latest currently), I need to prevent the access to a third party role to all methods but one in a SOAP service. In other words, I need that particular role to have access only to one particular method among all of the availables in the service.

Normally, a usual method level securization consists of annotation with `@Secure("MY_ROLE")`. This makes the method only to be accessible for that role.

Is it possible to tell Spring Security Core to do the opposite. I.e, configure it in a way that certain user only has access to the secured method.

Of course, the workaround could be:

```
// Method accessible by anyone but third party role
@Secured({"GOOD_ROLE1", "GOOD_ROLE2", "GOOD_ROLE3"})
public void methodAccessibleByAnyoneButThirdPartyRole(){
}

// Method accessible by anyone, including third party role
@Secured({"GOOD_ROLE1", "GOOD_ROLE2", "GOOD_ROLE3", "THIRD_PARTY_ROLE"})
public void methodAccessibleByAnyone(){
}
```

Other workaround would consist of just creating a new service only with the method to be restricted.

But is there any annotation option to get the same straightaway? Something like `@PreAuthorize("!hasRole('THIRD_PARTY_ROLE')")` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Spring Security [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) you can use any Spring Expression Language (SpEL) in `@PreAuthorize`

> Any Spring-EL functionality is available within the expression, so you
>   can also access properties on the arguments. For example, if you
>   wanted a particular method to only allow access to a user whose
>   username matched that of the contact, you could write
>
> @PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
>     public void doSomething(Contact contact);

So you can use:

```
@PreAuthorize("!hasRole('THIRD_PARTY_ROLE')")
```

Also as more readable variant:

```
@PreAuthorize("not hasRole('THIRD_PARTY_ROLE')")
```